# Missing line in "Follow UDP Stream" in wireshark

Tags: udp, wireshark, gnuradio

I am streaming raw UDP packets (rf data) from GNU Radio to Octave (or any other program).  The data consists of 390625  4 byte floats per second.  This is 1562500 bytes per second.  When GNU Radio streams UDP, there is no header or sequence number in the UDP data, it's just raw floats.  Because this is localhost to localhost, I am able to use a very large MTU.

Attached is a screenshot of Wireshark after right clicking and doing "Follow UDP Stream".  There is a "blank" part of the Hex Dump at 0x6F38C8.  I don't understand what this means?  (I know that UDP does not provide reliable delivery and packets can be dropped and arrive out of order at any moment).  Any help would be great!

[image: Wireshark Blank line in UDP Stream Hex Dump]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank part is simply used as a barrier to differentiate between 2 *UDP* packets, solely for your convenience.

- If you track down that exact data in the normal *wireshark* window you'll notice that the data before the blank part belongs to a certain UDP packet and that the data after the blank part belongs to the subsequent UDP packet.
- The HEX numbers on the left specify the offset of the first byte of the line from the beginning of the stream in that direction (i.e. in the half blank line, the byte `0x08` has `0x6F38C8` bytes sent before it in that direction). Since the half blank line has just `8` bytes, the offset of the next line is `0x6F38C8 + 0x8 = 0x6F38D0`. This is another indicator that the blank part isn't used as a filler for certain data that couldn't be represented due to some obscure reason.
- Note that it would be impossible for *wireshark* to know whether data is lost and represent it to you in any manner, since *UDP* is unreliable (that is, unless the underlying protocol maintains certain counters by itself, and is parsed by *wireshark*).